# How to Prevent Activity to be restart when orientation changes in android?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am working on android application. When I change the orientation of device, activity restarts.
I have applied all `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"` but still its not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Im not very sure but as far as i know, not possible, what is the problem you facing if the app is restarted? you can always save activity state in bundle.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code in your manifest file with respective activity.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: But it will fix application in portrait mode . i want to change orientation dynamically but don't want to restart activity.

Comment: Check your device orientation settings. Auto rotation should be on

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the orientation change by using either

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Otherwise,

```
onCreate(); // will run every time the activity is recreated.
```

To avoid losing data, you can save it in this callback:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
    icicle.putLong("myLong", myLongValue);
}
```

And restore it like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    if (icicle != null)
        myLongValue = icicle.getLong("myLong");

}
```

Hope this helps!